# What is Pikablu, and how can I get him?

Tags: pokemon-series

I've heard a lot of rumors about Pikablu, is he real or not?

If he's real, where can I find him? Do I need cheats to get him?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you can see from [this](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Marill_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) page, Pikablu was a rumored pokemon, which wound up being Marill **(#183)**, the evolution of [Azurill](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Azurill_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) **(#298)**. You will see in the comments at the bottom:

*"For months prior to the release of Pokémon Gold and Silver, Marill was often incorrectly referred to as "Pikablu", likely because of its slight resemblance to Pikachu. "*

Comment: Thanks for the ansert, i wish i could vote you up but i dont have the rep yet

Comment: @MaartenKuilman I do it for you then =)

Comment: @MaartenKuilman I am pretty sure you can upvote answers to your own question regaurdless of your rep. Also np, thats why we're here. :)

Comment: @Emerica. Nope he can't. [You have to have 15+ rep to up-vote](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: Marill is #183, not #298.  (Azurill was introduced the generation after Marill & Azumarill.)

Comment: @jwodder Ahh yes, you know what they say about assumptions... Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Pikablu is not a real Pokemon. As [the bulbapedia article](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Marill_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29#Trivia) explains, before the second generation of Pokemon games (Silver and Gold) was released, images of Marill were released and fans called it Pikablu.

Answer (score 1):

It's Marill.

I believe Pokémon the First Movie Trading Cards are the source of confusion. The first release of "Peacemaker Pikachu" card (before GSC was released) mentioned Buru (Snubbull) and Pikablu (Marill). The error was corrected in the release after GSC release (well, mostly, it misspelled Snubbull anyway).

On the scan below, I show the difference between two versions. The top one is the original version from which Pikablu comes. The second was released after GSC, and it fixes Pikablu error (but somehow it still misspells Snubbull).

Considering that it's the only instance where Marill's name appears before GSC release, it's easy to assume that Pikablu is actually Marill's name.

[image]